# How to read/write a hard disk through system IO ports?

Tags: io, ide, x86

I recently want to read hard disk using asm language, trying to directly read a hard disk through hard disk IO ports. I only know the IO ports for IDE hard disk controller are 0x170~0x177 and 0x1f0~0x1f7. But I don't find anything useful documents to solve the problem. Could somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: What is your operating system?  For protected mode operating systems (most current oses), non-kernel programs cannot write directly to ports.

Comment: Actually this program run in system boot loader, when there dose not exist an operating system. Using BIOS interrupt (int 13h) could read hard disk. But if I disable the bios interrupt, how can I do the work?

Comment: I don't know of an official reference for talking to ports, but I did see some sample code at http://forum.sysinternals.com/reading-disk-i-o-ports_topic13113.html and I also saw this that looked interesting: http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_PIO_Mode

Comment: Thank you for your help @DavidWohlferd. Your comment is very helpful to me. I can find the corresponding asm code from the link (http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_PIO_Mode)